# How do I remove <p> tag from django richtextfield?

Tags: django

I am getting `p` tag displayed after I post an image or question with ckeditor editor in Django. .How can I remove the tag and get the image or text be displayed correctly.

[image: Display of current result]

Answer (score 1):

Let me add this here. At the time of writing this answer, I couldn't find any way to customize the CKEditor but there's a handy method in Django that strips away the HTML tags from a string. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.strip_tags. For instance, if you are using Django forms you can use this method when you are validating the form that has CKEditor.

```py
    from django.utils.html import strip_tags

    def clean_content(self):
        blog = self.cleaned_data["blog"]
        return strip_tags(value=blog)
```

This method will remove the HTML tags and return the strings only

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly state that the content in template should be considered safe. You can use `safe` filter ([Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe)) to do that so for variable `text_content` in your template you should do `{{ text_content | safe }}`.